# Save in DataFrame unique values for every column

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

If I have a data (df) like this:

```
X1 X2 X3 
A  A  C
B  A  C
C  B  C
```

With the next fuction:

```
for col in df:
    print(pd.unique(df[col]))
```

It returns something like:

```
[A,B,C]
[A,B]
[C]
```

¿How can I save the return of the fuction in a DataFrame?, I would like to see it like this:

```
X1 X2 X3 
A  A  C
B  B  
C
```

Thanks you !

Comment: how many columns there are in your original dataframe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use lambda function with `Series` constructor and then repalce missing values:

```
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(pd.unique(x))).fillna('')
```

Or use [`Series.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)).fillna('')
```

---

```
print (df1)
  X1 X2 X3
0  A  A  C
1  B  B   
2  C
```

Comment: This was one great answer, at each refresh it improved drastically :) Even as I will complete my comment, it would be improved 10 fold :D

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
raw_data = {}
for counter, col in enumerate(df):
    raw_data['X%s' %counter] = pd.unique(df[col])
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = list(raw_data.keys()))
```